# hadoop 2.7.2 HDFS: no such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have this:

[image]

I had also tried to edit this:

`export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib`

as

`export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib`

in `~/.bashrc`

But still I am getting a warning message and I'm not able to solve the problem.

> Unable to create the directory

I'm using this code to create the directory for twitter analysis:

`hadoop fs -mkdir hdfs://localhost:54310/home/vipal/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/twitter_data`

Comment: Try `hadoop fs -mkdir -p hdfs://localhost:54310/home/vipal/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/twitter_data`

Answer (score 0):

Notice how `hadoop fs -ls` says `.: No such file or directory`?

First, you must create your home directory, which is `/user` in HDFS.

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/$(whoami)
```

(You should also `chown` and `chmod` that directory)

Then, you can place files into a `twitter_data` directory.

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir twitter_data
hdfs dfs -put <local_files> twitter_data
```

(I removed `hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode` because that doesn't make sense)